# strange if statement behavior on linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a shell script and have come across some weird if behavior.

My question is simple, why does `[[ "╝" = [█] ]]` evaluate to true?  Is it because they are both uncommon ascii characters?  On my mac, it evaluates fine.

note:
The █ does need to be in brackets.

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: I recommend submitting a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation does not depend on platform (mac or other). It depends on current locale settings:

```
$ LANG=C
$ if [[ "╝" = [█] ]]; then echo y; else echo n; fi
n
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ if [[ "╝" = [█] ]]; then echo y; else echo n; fi
y
```

We can try to detect which locales matches the expression via simple script:

```
for i in $(locale -a)
do
   export LANG=$i
   echo -n "LANG=$LANG   "
   if [[ "╝" = [█] ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
done
```

and see that the UTF-8 locales matches the expression. When locale is set to UTF-8 capable then bash interprets the UTF-8 characters in different way and that is the reason why the result are different.

Nevertheless I think it is a bug because it should return false even if locale with UTF-8 support is set.

Comment: It is a bug. And it does depend on the platform and version. I can reproduce this on my Ubuntu 14.04LTS with bash 4.3.30, but not on OS X with either system bash (3.2.57(1), back from 2007) or brewed bash (4.3.33(1)): `bash -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8; [[ "╝" = [█] ]]'` or `bash -c 'LANG=C; [[ "╝" = [█] ]]'` both return 1 no matter what.

Comment: Also, I tried to blame this bug on encoding but failed. Even if you disassemble both UTF-8 characters into bytes, the first string won't match the second string (considered as a `[]` pattern). Maybe we have to look at the source code to tell what's exactly wrong.

Comment: I submitted a bug report, but I have very limited experience in non scripting languages so I'm afraid I won't be much help in looking for the problem in the source.